# Supplementing advanced material in Griffiths-Harris

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, several-complex-variables

I am looking for literature to supplement the treatment in Griffiths-Harris of the following topics:

**Chapter 3**

- $\S 1$ on Distributions and currents. This material is also briefly discussed in [Demailly's](https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/%7Edemailly/manuscripts/agbook.pdf) book, but I wanted to see a more detailed exposition of smoothing of currents.
- $\S 2$ on Applications of currents: LeLong numbers, Levi extension theorems and proper mapping theorems. These topics are covered in Demailly's book, but I was also looking for a less terse exposition.
- $\S 4$ on Fixed-Point and Residue formulas. I am not even aware of any other textbook exposition of these results.

**Chapter 5**

- $\S 1$ and $\S 2$ on Residues and their applications. There is abundant literature on multidimensional residues, but mostly with complex-analytic applications in mind, while I want to find the exposition geared towards geometry, just like Griffiths-Harris but hopefully less terse.

I would also be fine with on-line notes on these topics.

Comment: Just a question: Have you looked at DeRham's original book? He treats smoothing of currents and homology of currents quite seriously.

Comment: @TedShifrin, thank you. I had indeed looked at it before writing the post, and it seemed that the order of exposition was very different, so to study parts I needed for G&H I would have needed to study very big chunks of unrelated material.

Comment: You might look for some papers by Griffiths and J. King. Several on currents and applications.